Oracle date range for consecutive records
I'm trying to figure out how to write a query to select date range for consecutive records.
I have a table called product, it has below columns and data.



product_id
status
status_date




123
A
09-12-2024


123
A
07-15-2024


123
I
06-01-2024


123
A
05-01-2024


123
I
04-01-2024


245
I
08-24-2024


245
A
06-01-2024


245
I
05-01-2024



output is



product_id
status
status_date




123
A
07-15-2024


245
I
08-24-2024



Because the latest status is A and its been A since 07-15-2024 for product 123 (by checking for previous status of A consecutively)
And latest status for product 245 is I and its previous status is A so pick only the current I status date i.e. 08-24-2024.
I tried connect by and was not able to figure it out

Is the specified 'output' the current result or the desired result? Can you also show us your current query attempt?

First calculate group by (product_id, status) and then analytic to get first/last values per group:
with data(product_id, status, status_date) as (
    select 123, 'A', to_date('09-12-2024', 'mm-dd-yyyy') union all
    select 123, 'A', to_date('07-15-2024', 'mm-dd-yyyy') union all
    select 123, 'I', to_date('06-01-2024', 'mm-dd-yyyy') union all
    select 123, 'A', to_date('05-01-2024', 'mm-dd-yyyy') union all
    select 123, 'I', to_date('04-01-2024', 'mm-dd-yyyy') union all
    select 245, 'I', to_date('08-24-2024', 'mm-dd-yyyy') union all
    select 245, 'A', to_date('06-01-2024', 'mm-dd-yyyy') union all
    select 245, 'I', to_date('05-01-2024', 'mm-dd-yyyy') 
)
select distinct d.product_id, d.status,
    nvl (
        first_value(status_date) over(partition by product_id, grp 
            order by status_date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),
        last_value(status_date) over(partition by product_id, grp 
            order by status_date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) 
    ) as status_date
from (
    select d.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by product_id order by status_date desc)
        - row_number() over(partition by product_id, status order by status_date desc) as grp
    from data d
) d
where grp = 0
order by product_id, status_date desc
;

123 A   15/07/24
245 I   24/08/24


One option is to detect changes of status value per product_id and get last date per product to be used in Having clause to filter the aggregated data:
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
  product ( product_id, status, status_date ) AS
    ( Select 123,   'A',    To_Date('09-12-2024', 'mm-dd-yyyy') From Dual Union All
      Select 123,   'A',    To_Date('07-15-2024', 'mm-dd-yyyy') From Dual Union All
      Select 123,   'I',    To_Date('06-01-2024', 'mm-dd-yyyy') From Dual Union All
      Select 123,   'A',    To_Date('05-01-2024', 'mm-dd-yyyy') From Dual Union All
      Select 123,   'I',    To_Date('04-01-2024', 'mm-dd-yyyy') From Dual Union All
      Select 245,   'I',    To_Date('08-24-2024', 'mm-dd-yyyy') From Dual Union All
      Select 245,   'A',    To_Date('06-01-2024', 'mm-dd-yyyy') From Dual Union All
      Select 245,   'I',    To_Date('05-01-2024', 'mm-dd-yyyy') From Dual
    ), 

... create a cte to detect changes of status within the same product_id
  grid as 
    ( Select   product_id, status, status_date,
               Case When status != Lead(status) 
                                    Over(Partition By product_id 
                                    Order By status_date Desc)
               Then status
               End as last_stat, 
               Case When status != Lead(status) 
                                    Over(Partition By product_id 
                                    Order By status_date Desc)
               Then status_date
               End as last_stat_date
      From     product
    ) 

--      M a i n    S Q L :
Select     g.product_id, g.last_stat as status, Max(g.last_stat_date) as status_date
From       grid g
Inner Join product p ON(p.product_id = g.product_id And p.status_date = g.last_stat_date )
Where      g.last_stat Is Not Null
Group By   g.product_id, g.last_stat
Having     Max(g.last_stat_date) = ( Select Max(last_stat_date) From grid Where product_id = g.product_id Group By product_id)
Order By   g.product_id

/*    R e s u l t :
PRODUCT_ID S STATUS_D
---------- - --------
       123 A 15.07.24
       245 I 24.08.24      */

